# AfterInsertRow, setCell. programmatically change the content of the cell

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to JqGrid, so please bear with me. I am having some problems with styling the cells when I use a `showlink` formatter.
In my configuration I set up the AfterInsertRow and it works fine if I just display simple text:

```
 afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData) {
   if (aData.Security == `C`) {
     jQuery('#list').setCell(rowid, 'Doc_Number', '', { color: `red` });
 } else
 {
   jQuery('#list').setCell(rowid, 'Doc_Number', '', { color: `green` });
 }
}, ...
```

This code works just fine, but as soon as I add a formatter

```
{'Doc_Number, ..., 'formatter: ’showlink’, formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: ’url.aspx’}
```

the above code doesn't work because a new element is added to the cell

```
<a href='url.aspx'>cellValue</a>
```

Is it possible to access programmatically the new child element using something like the code above and change the style?

```
`<a href='url.aspx' style='color: red;'>cellValue</a>` etc.
```

UPDATE: In order to work you have to do as follow:

```
jQuery('#list').setCell(rowid, 'Doc_Number', '', 'redLink');
```

CSS Class

```
.redLink a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a class to the cell:

```
jQuery('#list').setCell(rowid, 'Doc_Number', '', 'redLink');
```

Then define a CSS class along these lines:

```
.redLink a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, it doesn't work. Now it display 'redlink' as cell text.

Comment: Hi again,
it actually works if you invert the last two parameters:
jQuery('#list').setCell(rowid, 'Doc_Number', '', 'redLink'); 

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I'm glad you got it to work! FWIW, I just updated my answer.